# require.server in not a function Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm started to learn node and I faced this issue

when I wanted to create an http server for the socket.io, I this exception is thrown

> require(...).server is not a function

and here is my code

```
var express = require('express')

var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

var app = express()

var http = require('http').server(app)

var io = require('socket.io')
```

So How could I solve this error

thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is just a spelling mistake. `server` should be capatalised. `var http = require('http').Server(app)` :)

Comment: Wow it was already! thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mind the PascalCase. It is a static method.

```js
var http = require('http').Server(app)
```

Comment: yes It worked, thanks